# Version of wikipedia in python package wiki

Tags: python, wikipedia

I am using python 3.4. I have installed the "wikipedia" package.

I have the following queries

1. Which version of wiki pages does this package use?
2. Can I change the version of wiki that is being used (through a api call maybe)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean what revision of a page is fetched? That would be the most recent. To get older revisions, see the MediaWiki API documentation.

Comment: ...or do you mean what Wikipedia edition (Arabic, Bengali, etc)?

Comment: Thanks leo - I meant the revision. I was able to choose the language

Comment: Ok, then I think you'll have to work directly with the API, or use another library like `wikitools`